# How do I increment a number at the end of a variable in Python

Tags: python, variables

I'm attempting to learn Python with only bash experience.  But I think I may be doing this wrong, and maybe this is poor design.

```
line1="foo"
line2="bar"
line3="foobar"

i = 1 
while i <= 3:
    target.write(line+i) 
    target.write("\n")
    i = i + 1
```

Is there a way for me to use the count increment to call the line variable for the write function?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `call the line variable`?

Comment: you need to increment `i` in your `while` loop. Otherwise it'll never end.

Comment: `line + i` would add/concatenate the value of the variable `line` with the value of the variable `i` (types permitting). It does not create a reference to one of `line1`, `line2`, or `line3`.

Answer (score 3):

Store the strings in a list, then iterate over the list.

```
lines = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

for line in lines:
    target.write(line)
    target.write('\n')
```

This way there's no need to maintain a separate `i` variable just for iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
test = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for index, value in enumerate(test):
    print index, value
```

Comment: `enumerate` isn't called for in the question. `i` is used in an erroneous attempt to iterate over the names of some variables, not as part of the output.